# File size is always zero when images uploaded to google cloud storage from Android using JSON api

Tags: android, json, google-cloud-storage

I am using the below code snippet to upload an image to google cloud storage from Android using JSON api. Although I have tested the file size before upload ,which is not zero, the file size becomes zero after upload.

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri); //imageUri is obtained after the image is chosen
Storage storage = getStorage(); 
//The below three lines are a test to get the file size 
Bitmap selectedImage1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
byte[] imageByte = Utilities.getBytesFromBitmap(selectedImage1);
int size = imageByte.length;
StorageObject object = new StorageObject().setName("myobject")
.setContentDisposition("attachment");
String contentType = "image/jpeg";
InputStreamContent content = new InputStreamContent(contentType, is);
content.setRetrySupported(true);
Storage.Objects.Insert insert = storage.objects().insert("mybucket.appspot.com", object, content); //bucketname changed
insert.execute();
```

I have taken a look at most of the related questions in stackoverflow but could not figure out a solution yet.

Comment: BitmapFactory already read your stream is when you call new InputStreamContent on is. So there is nothing left to read any more. Besides that 'int size' will not represent the number of bytes in the file. Throw away BitmapFactory and use File class to determine file size.

Comment: @greenapps : Removed reading by the BitmapFactory and it worked ! Thank you very much .